# JavaScript array of objects with a field and child array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is this not valid JavaScript?

I have an array. Each item in the array has a title field, and also a child array. The child array has objects which contain an img field also sometimes also a content field.

```
const content = [
  {
    "title": "First title",
    [
      {"img": img1, "content": "This is content"},
      {"img": img2},
      {"img": img3}
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Second title",
    [
      {"img": img4, "content": "This is also content"},
      {"img": img5},
      {"img": img6}
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: No, I think you're referring to the property names wrapped in quotes. Those are totally valid in JavaScript.

Comment: You don't have property names for the arrays. Objects (curly braces) are made up of key-value pairs, that means every entity inside needs a proper key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no property name for the nested arrays.

```
const content = [
{
    "title": "First title",
    "missingKey1" : [
      {"img": img1, "content": "This is content"},
      {"img": img2},
      {"img": img3}
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Second title",
    "missingKey2" : [
      {"img": img4, "content": "This is also content"},
      {"img": img5},
      {"img": img6}
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: No, the "title" keys are in two separate objects.